# css - oversized div within small div

Tags: css

I need to make a menu that looks like this:

[image]

The upper entries need to have a right margin of (lets say) 20px.

Problem arises, when I add the sub-menus, especially like the red one with the «large Menu-Entry». The top menu needs to stay in place and all the sub-menus need to be centered under that top menu. But either the top-entry is enlarged (which makes the green part shift to the right) or the sub-entries aren't positioned at the center of the top-entry...
As the menu-entries are dynamic, I can't predict how wide they are and thus I can't apply any math.

Also - the sub-entries are only visible, if the user is on the according page (means - the green part only shows «Menu1» if the user is on the red page)

I «could» use some javascript to do it after the page loaded, but I'm trying to avoid that.

I tried all sorts of stuff, including negative margins and whatnot - but nothing seems to work... Any ideas?

[edit]

some html here - tried to fumble around like crazy with no results (except the one from Brad, but that one doesn't work with IE)

```
<div class="center">

            <div class="menu-container">
                <div class="menu-title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="menu-items">
                    Testomat<br />
                    Yo, this is a long text
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu-container">
                <div class="menu-title">Title 1</div>
                <div class="menu-items">
                    Testomat<br />
                    Yo, this is a long text
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-container{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

.menu-items, .menu-title{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the html you're working with?

Comment: uh - actually, I tried 100 things right now - nothing of that works... will try to post the code anyway, though...

Comment: Are you willing to change the html mark-up to make this substantially easier?

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't care about IE:** Have you tried using `display:table-cell`?

You could try something like:

```
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-title">
      Menu1
  </div>
  <div class="menu-items">
      <div class="menu-item">large menu item</div>
      <div class="menu-item">sub</div>
      <div class="menu-item">sub</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.menu-container {
   display : table;
   width: 100px;
}

.menu-title, .menu-items {
  display : table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Naturally, the content within the `table-cell`s will wrap to 100px.

Comment: But note that `display:table-cell` **won't** work in IE... (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: Great - so I've got an answer for all browsers except IE... What Brad suggested works in Safari & Firefox, though - so I just try to find a way around IE... (I LOATHE IE...)

Comment: I have a few months ago the opportunity of making a page that didn't need to support any version of IE (it was an internal administration page accessed only by 4 people, three managers that used Firefox and a designer that used a Mac), and it was very liberating... I'm eager for the day that I don't need to take into account anything lower than IE8 (which is not perfect but pass the acid2 test).

Comment: I wish I could do that with that page I'm working on... Looks like I have to talk to the designer... nothing seems to really work :(

Answer (score 0):

My first approach uses different html mark-up to your own, but gives the visual effect you you're looking for with, perhaps, a slight increase in semantics:

#### html:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Title One</dt>
    <dd>Testomat</dd>
    <dd>Yo, this is a long text</dd>
</dl>
<dl>    
    <dt>Title Two</dt>
    <dd>Testomat</dd>
    <dd>Yo, this is a long text</dd>
</dl>
```

#### css:

```
dl {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #0f0;
}
dl:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

[Demo of the above at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4nKCj/).

---

**Edited,** to add the following:

On looking at your posted mark-up, and applying the css:

```
.menu-container {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #0f0;
}

.menu-container:nth-child(odd) {
    color: #f00;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4nKCj/2/)

I'm not sure why you're experiencing difficulties. Admittedly, at the moment, I'm only able to test on Chrome and IE 8 (Win XP), but the above seems to work. Am I missing something important in your problem description?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Thomas!

I looked at the demos on JS-Fiddle, but the result is not what I'm aiming for. If you look at the image I posted, you'll see that the «very long entry» shouldn't have line breaks. That's the catch... Your Demo does apply line breaks, though (at least it does in Safari an FF)...

Comment: What do you want to happen when a single line of text overflows the container?

Comment: Well - look at the image in my original post - that's what the whole thing should look like. There will be only one of the sub-menus visible at a time, though, so the submenus actually won't overlap. So the overflow should be visible and it should be on one line only...